# Nested jquery queue doesn't run

Tags: jquery

Any reason why console.dir line never runs? can I nest queues?

```
  //Rotate letter W to M of Wovi.es
  $(".logo a span").delay(5000).queue(function(){
    $(this).addClass("rotate").delay(400).queue(function(){
      //$(this).removeClass("rotate");
      console.dir($(this)); // This never runs
    });
  });
```

Obvious workaround I can see is just to have two separate functions like so:

```
  //Rotate letter W to M of Wovi.es
  $(".logo a span").delay(5000).queue(function(){
    $(this).addClass("rotate");
  });
  $(".logo a span").delay(5400).queue(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("rotate");
  });
```

But why wouldn't first one work?

p.s. actually my second code doesn't work either.

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GqmQB/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny as you can see Z never logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#test").delay(5000).queue(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    $(this).addClass("rotate").delay(1400).queue(function(){
        $this.removeClass('rotate');
    }).dequeue();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BhpfX/

Note I changed it to 1400 on the inner delay so it's more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

`dequeue` is the key when dealing with multiple queues.

From jQuery docs:

*When jQuery.dequeue() is called, the next function on the queue is removed from the queue, and then executed. This function should in turn (directly or indirectly) cause jQuery.dequeue() to be called, so that the sequence can continue.*

```
$('.logo').delay(500).queue(function(){
    $(this).addClass('rotate').delay(1000)
      .queue(function(next) {
       alert('working');      
    }).dequeue();
});
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JcARs/)